# Можно ли добавить меню под стандартную клавиатуру (Android Studio)

Tags: android-studio, меню, клавиатура

Здравствуйте!
Я хочу сделать так, что бы при открытии клавиатуры самым нижним блоком в приложении оставалось меню (в моем случае меню - обычный LinearLayout), примерно как на картинке:[image: расположение блоков]

Это можно реализовать через встроенную клавиатуру или надо писать свою?